Google Cloud Function - Invalid login
I upgraded a 4 years old cloud function from gen 1 to gen 2 using defineSecret instead of functions.config() to get environment variables and using OAuth2 authentication instead of having my gmail setup to authorize "less secure apps".
The function deploys successfully but when I run it I get an "invalid user or password" error. The function is a simple one that takes the data from a contact form and emails it to me, using my gmail as sender.
I have OAuth consent screen on testing mode with my email as a test user.
I generated a refresh token with OAuth 2.0 Playground using this API: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send
Here is the exact log:
Access Token obtained successfully
Error creating transport: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.
EDIT
Here is the function:
const clientId = defineSecret("CLIENT_ID");
const clientSecret = defineSecret("CLIENT_SECRET");
const refreshToken = defineSecret("REFRESH_TOKEN");

async function getAccessToken(oauth2Client) {
  try {
    const { token } = await oauth2Client.getAccessToken();
    return token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error getting access token:', error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to get access token: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

const createTransport = async () => {
  try {
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      await clientId.value(),
      await clientSecret.value(),
      "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
    );

    oauth2Client.setCredentials({
      refresh_token: await refreshToken.value()
    });

    const accessToken = await getAccessToken(oauth2Client);
if (!accessToken) {
      throw new Error('Failed to obtain access token');
    }

    console.log('Access Token obtained successfully');
    
    const transportConfig = {
      host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      port: 465,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        type: 'OAuth2',
        user: await emailSender.value(),
        clientId: await clientId.value(),
        clientSecret: await clientSecret.value(),
        refreshToken: await refreshToken.value(),
        accessToken,
      },
    };

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(transportConfig);
    
    await transporter.verify();
    console.log('SMTP connection verified successfully');
    
    return transporter;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating transport:', error);
    throw new Error(`Failed to create transport: ${error.message}`);
  }
};



The problem was related to the API that I was using. Since my function does nothing else than sending an email with my gmail account, I thought that using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send in the OAuth 2.0 playground would be enough but no.
I had to authorize full access to my gmail account with https://mail.google.com/  and now the function is working.

Have you binded the secret to the function?
If you have, you can share the part of the code where you initialized the secret?

yes, I edited my question with some more code

@AngeLoron ensure the secret is set in Google Secrets Manager and that your function can access it. You can use this link as guide: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/secrets#gcloud

Yes, it is because I can see the values when I run firebase functions:secrets:access CLIENT_SECRET and just for the sake of it I also tried to console.log it and when I ran the function it showed the value in the logs.
